# How can I set the default picture style in Outlook 2007

Tags: outlook

I do a lot of project management, which includes taking tons of screenshots of our apps throughout the day and emailing them to developers/business sponsors/etc.  Does anyone know how to set the default picture style in Outlook 2007 so I can automatically have it add a shadow background without clicking through the ribbon bar every time?

I do this about 30-50 times a day so even a few clicks saved could add up.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: I have the same question for Outlook 2010 (or I could upgrade to 2013 if they've added a feature to address this).